# How does that have anything to do with it?

Tags: grammar, spoken-english

Recently I was having a conversation in which someone said something off topic:

> Person 1: Hey do you like video games?
>   Person 2: Yeah my favorite is.....
>   Person 3: I'm hungry.
>   Person 1: How does that have anything to do with it?

Is the phrase “How does that have anything to do with it” correct?

Comment: This could have also been closed as a proofreading request, which is expressly off-topic. I recommend a tour of our [help center](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help), as well as our [Contributor's Guide](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/contributors-guide-to-english-language-learners).

Comment: More common would be *What does that have to do with it?* The *how* version, while not wrong, has a slightly different nuance to it.